# In Rails 3.2.x, what is the proper way to set default values for instance variables used across actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller

We want to use a default name and description for every page rendered, unless defined otherwise by an action.

What's the right way to do this?

We're on Rails 3.2.12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want variables across the entire scope of your site, I normally define a before_filter on ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :intialize_var

  def initialize_var
    @var = "some default"
  end
end
```

Then override that filter manually in controllers wherever I want - like so:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController

  def initialize_var
    @var = 'parents just dont understand'
  end
end
```

You can just use `@var` in your views and you're good to go.

Comment: Thanks, I assume if this applies to only one controller, just use the before_filter in that controller?

Comment: Oh, for a single controller I would use a before filter and override the `@var` in whatever action needs custom values.  This solution is assuming you are using the `@var` in your application layout (or similar view template/partial) from potentially many controllers (or all controllers).